# What is the most efficient way to find common ancestors on a large remote GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github, graphql, version-control

##### Methods that I have explored:

So, there are dozens of ways to interact with a GitHub repository. Methods include Github GraphQL, GitHub REST API, `git clone/fetch`-ing, and interacting with the Github's underlying git services directly.

I have found various ways to form trees of commit SHAs, but almost every method I have found has inefficiencies, that I can't seem to resolve.

## Goal:

I simply want to find the **SHA of the common ancestor of 2 branches**.

##### What I know:

Branches in git are like pointers to commit shas. The branch itself doesn't actually track what commits are on the branch, just what commit is at the tip of the branch. The commits then keep track of their parents. So, the conventional way to determine the common ancestor of 2 branches is to iterate over each parent commit starting from the branch tip, until you find a commit that is shared by both branches. This is how `git merge-base` works.

The problem with `git merge-base` is that you have to at a minimum perform a `git fetch` on the repository. This is inefficient, because `git fetch` downloads more than just the commit SHAs from the origin.

##### REST and GraphQL Problem:

So, I was thinking of using GitHub's REST and or GraphQL APIs. The problem with both:

- **neither have a built-in merge-base method (at least as far as I know)**, so I would have to iterate over the commit histories of each branch manually, which is not terrifically efficient, especially if I am using REST.

**The particular repository I'm trying to run `merge-base` is [chromium/chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium)** *which is an absolutely massive repository.*

### Inefficiencies caused by large-scale repositories:

I am trying to find the common ancestors of the main branch and the feature-branches associated with each Git tag. Sounds pretty simple, except for the fact that there are **almost *27,000* tags and associated feature-branches on the [chromium/chromium](https://github.com/chromium/chromium) repository**.

So, with that said, trying to manually run a merge-base on the repository with a simple GraphQL Query is still far too inefficient. *With a rate limit of 500,000 (5000 points), At 27,000 feature-branches*, **I could theoretically only iterate over 20 commits per branch before hitting the GraphQL rate limit**. To make that worse, I only expect the amount of tags to increase on that repository over time.

REST is out of question (as far as I know anyway), because the rate limits for REST are even further restrictive.

##### Possible alternative solution:

I am unsure if there is a way to optimize the methods that I have explored above, but I have also considered interacting with the underlying communication services.

I believe git communicates at the Application Layer, using HTTP to communicate with repositories with custom HTTP headers. This method would allow me to interact, not only with Chromium's GitHub mirror, [but the actual repository hosted by Piper/Gitiles](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/).

However, I am unsure if there is a method to manually merge-base with that. I was wondering if it is possible to just download the commit SHAs (and their parents) given a target branch and no other metadata, but I would have no idea how to do that or if that would be efficient. I can't seem to find any good documentation on the underlying communication services offered by git repos.

Comment: The [“commit graph”](https://git-scm.com/docs/commit-graph) is used to compute merge bases among other things. Maybe that’s all that you need.

Comment: You could do a [tree-less clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/) with `git clone --filter=tree:0`, that's at least faster than a full clone, but still gets you all commit information required to find merge bases.

Comment: @BenjaminW. does that work? I thought that git command was invalid?

Comment: I tried @BenjaminW.’s suggestion. Clone took 10 minutes. Space taken by the working tree and the repository is 6.4G.

Comment: `git merge-base main 32.0.1659.2` takes 1.238s.

Comment: @Guildenstern was that on a fresh `git init ... get fetch`?, If you ran that on your preexisting clone, that is why it took so fast.

Comment: nevermind I see. You meant that you ran `git clone --filter=tree:0; git merge-base main 32.0.1659.2` and that **seems to currently be holding the best efficiency at 10 minutes** and an additional second from the merge-base

Comment: Yes. Well the ten minutes are amortized over all the `git merge-base` invocations. I think I picked an old tag. A newer tag seems to take something like 150ms. I would think that 1–2s for that command is a worst case.

Comment: Is it possible to make it more efficient with a treeless-fetch (if that is even possible)? git-clone is known to be beefier than git-fetch, but with it being treeless, I don't know how much more we could skin off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This takes about one minute on my machine:

```
git clone --bare --filter=tree:0 https://github.com/chromium/chromium chromium-bare
```

Now the repository takes about 764M.

`--filter=tree:0` avoids trees and blobs (suggested by [Benjamin
W.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76138847/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-common-ancestors-on-a-large-remote-github?noredirect=1#comment134275259_76138847)). `--bare` means that we don’t have to check out a working tree.

This takes 19 seconds:

```
git commit-graph write
```

Let’s try to find an old tag:

```
git tag --sort=version:refname
```

I don’t know how Chromium is versioned so I’m just guessing that these
tags can be sorted in this way. The tag `3.0.195.25` is from 2014.

This takes about 1.3s:

```
git merge-base main 3.0.195.25
```

Let’s say that that is a worst case. With about 27,000 tags it should
take at most `1.3 * 27000 = 35100` seconds to compute all the merge
bases (assuming that the runtime of the rest of the code is negligible),
or 9¾ hours.

#### Comparing `xargs` with (GNU) `parallel`

Computing the merge base between `master` and two hundred tags takes
about 2m18s:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' 'refs/tags/**' --count=200 | xargs -n 1 git merge-base master
```

I warmed up the disk (hopefully) by running the command one time
before the invocation.

Same procedure with `parallel` instead:

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:short)' 'refs/tags/**' --count=200 | parallel -n 1 git merge-base master
```

That takes 28s.

My CPU has four cores and eight threads.

That takes the total runtime down from 9¾ hours to approximately 1 hour and 10 minutes.

Comment: To cut the time of the last line, I would suggest a multithreaded solution.

I believe a multithreaded solution should work well with that last line. As far as I am aware, `merge-base` does not make any data changes to the git repo, so I don't expect a race condition. I imagine multithreading/load balancing that last line should increase the efficiency dramatically.

Comment: Though I've checked your contribution history on GH, and you probably know way more than I do considering you are a contributor to `git`

Comment: Only doc fixes.

Comment: Just so that I understand correctly, `git` preserves the `--filter` correct? So I can keep that treeless bare repository up to date simply by running `git fetch`?

Comment: @DaMaxContent Seems like it. I did a `git fetch origin` now and got `344.15 KiB`. I got ~50MiB on my regular clone which I made a little before the bare one.

Comment: Wow, I'm even more impressed with the results of GNU parallel. Assuming that is approximately average that takes the total runtime down from nearly 10 hrs to approximately 1hr and 10 minutes on a single machine.